# Does Node 11 REPL support import?

Tags: node.js, module

Based on this conversation I was hoping it might: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/22381

But when I tried it:

```
✗ nvm exec 11 node --experimental-modules  
Running node v11.1.0 (npm v6.4.1)
> (node:31601) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.

> 
> let pt = require("./src/constants/paymentTypes.js")
/Users/jcol53/work/orders/src/constants/paymentTypes.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { defineMessages, formatMessage } from '@tools/shared';
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Same result with `✗ nvm exec 11 node --experimental-vm-modules`

Is `import` going to be supported in the Node 11 or Node 12 REPL?

Comment: I was hoping someone would have had an answer. Same issue here 

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It does support but only as experimental feature, it means

- you should use --experimental-modules flag
- javascript file with "import" shall have extension .mjs

So the full command will look like

```
node --experimental-modules index.mjs
```

In your case 'paymentTypes.js' should be renamed to 'paymentTypes.mjs'.

Comment: Pretty sure the babel-node REPL didn't support import last time I tried it. Maybe it also expects `mjs`

Comment: I'll be damned if i can get this to work. `import paymentTypes from "./paymentTypes.mjs";` results in `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. Tried 3 other variations. The file only has one export and it's the default. Using node 11.

Comment: @jcollum right, babel-node REPL doesn't support import. As an option you might convert your code to CommonJS and then use node REPL

Comment: The repl doesn't have a file extension so it doesn't support modules. You have to execute a module file with an extension of .mjs (using nodemon or something) to have something like a repl running.

Comment: @Ashnur there's no way to run an mjs script and be thrown into a repl that supports ES Modules afterwards. I tried everything.